# How do I view and edit last expression used in a find in vi?

Tags: unix, vi

Is there a way to bring up the last regular expression used in vi for a search?  If I enter a long regular expression, it would be nice to just edit the expression if it was incorrect or other modifications needed to be made to it instead of entering the whole thing again.

**EDIT:** 
This is actually VI in AIX.  Things behave a bit differently.  I have re-tagged my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim, press <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, or <kbd>?</kbd> followed by <kbd>↑</kbd>